# Need mating PCB connector for Micro JST 1.25mm 2 pole Li Battery

Tags: identification, component-selection

I have spent hours to search for the mating connector fo the below battery connector.

**Source**: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0867KDMY7/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0867KDMY7)

**Image**: [image]

Please help me to find the right mating connector for PCB or guide me with right keywords to look for.
many thanks, in advance

I have found one: https://www.digikey.in/product-detail/en/amphenol-icc-fci/10114830-10102LF/609-5378-1-ND/8555649

**Promising**:
[image]
but not sure

Comment: really? https://www.benl.ebay.be/itm/Micro-JST-1-25mm-2-0mm-2-Pin-Male-Female-Connector-plug-with-Wires-Cables-Lipo-/232485892646 https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/32753277332.html https://www.amazon.com/micro-jst-1-25/s?k=micro+jst+1.25 https://opencircuit.be/Product/Micro-JST-2-Pin-1.25mm-male-female-connector https://www.banggood.com/JST-1_25mm-2-Pin-Micro-Male-Female-Connector-Plug-40mm-Wires-Cables-for-Blade-Inductrix-p-1125206.html?cur_warehouse=CN I can go on

Comment: I am able to find them. I am trying to find the mating connector for PCB mount. I am sorry for not talking clearly. I have to create a library as well for the part (Eagle EDA)

Comment: If you know the JST series number of what you have, then you know if you have the right mating connector.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Hmmm a product from Amazon doesn't have the datasheet. I might be fighting a lost war

Comment: Since there's no provided part number for the female I can't say for sure if this is right one. But here's one that I found https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/jst-sales-america-inc/BM02B-GHS-TBT-LF-SN-N/807800

Comment: The connector you found is made by Amphenol. It may not mate with a JST.